# from WebView in android back to a ListView

Tags: android

After a successful web view is loaded, now after some processing on the HTML page, I would like to return the control to the main screen. Is this possible in Android?

The control after the webview is launched, is in the browser, so after I make some ajax calls and then get a positive server side message. I would like the control goback to my Webview Activity.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change which control has focus?

Comment: My initial app looks like a ListView and when you select one option among the list, it takes you to a WebView.

When you are finished at the webview I want to go back to my first listview that had inflated when the app stareed.

Comment: Is the webview open my a new intent or a viewflipper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!

Let me post the code which worked for me

```
final class DemoJavaScriptInterface {
    //public String loginIDInfo = "URL selected from Main Screen :+"+nicu_app.urlSelected;
    private String someData = "Arun Sanjay";
    public String getData() { return someData; }
    public void setData(String abc) {
        someData = abc;
    }
}
```

In the HTML view

I was calling a function setPass which was initializing the variables.

function setPassData() {
    demo.setData("pass");
}

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` in the `Activity` with the `WebView`, and control will return to the `Activity` with the `ListView`.

Comment: I think I have to rephrase my question.

I would like to know if the javascript variables have been set properly from the webview and if set, go back to the listview

Comment: @Sana: That will be substantially more difficult. Use `addJavascriptInterface()` to make a Java object available to Javascript. Then, use a `javascript:` URL and `loadUrl()` in your Java code to execute some Javascript that checks your variables, then calls a method on the object you injected with `addJavascriptInterface()` to return the result for you. If you are simply looking to wait for the page to be loaded in its entirety, try using a `WebViewClient` and `onPageFinished()`.